# How can we intergrate kanji to be an available in the qpython 3 in the console side as it is in the interpreter side?

Tags: console, qpython, qpython3, kanji

I'm trying to figure out how I can type in kanji from the console side of qpython3. Maybe it's the phone i'm using. They say that the program acts differently depending on the phone/version/etc. Is anybody else experiencing this problem, maybe with another language? I don't get much of a problem with spanish.

Comment: Which input method do you use please ?

Comment: Input as in which language of unicode-8? If so i'm using the qwerty in english, spanish and japanese, I'm also using the 12  key method with japanese all under the brand "sky devices" and model is a platinum f5. I hope that with help. Thanks for your concern

Comment: Maybe you can try to input the kanji in other edit app, and copy & paste to qpython3's console. 

I think it's a temporary solution. : )

Comment: I'm going to actually try that if i didn't already. どぅも